# Лимитированное количество записей в базу данных

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, нужно сделать ограничение на количество записей.

Есть таблица продуктов и изображений. Связаны один-ко-многим (продукт-изображения). Нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новых изображений осуществлялась проверка количества записей с `products_id => $products->id` и польхователю отображалось предупреждение о том, что нельзя загружать больше `n` изображений.

Как это лучше оформить?

Comment: Перед тем как загрузить изображение, получите количество строк из базы (`COUNT` в SQL) по данному ID продукта. После условие, если число строк в базе меньше N, тогда добавляй, иначе вывести ошибку.

Comment: да, так и сделал

Comment: можно еще в шаблоне сделать проверку, если изображений много, то заблокировать кнопку для добавления картинок

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, имелось в виду представление и его форма? сделать проверку на стороне клиента? да, тоже вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как загрузить изображение, получите количество строк из базы (COUNT в SQL) по данному ID продукта. После условие, если число строк в базе меньше N, тогда добавляй, иначе вывести ошибку

(ответ из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879466/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85#comment1430792_879466))